# Project.json does not exist after creating a new asp.net core project or disapears when opening a solution with new tooling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have problem. I installed asp.net core and into my solution doesn't exists any project.json file

Here is screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What you are asking is totally unclear

Comment: I have installed MVC 6 and I'm trying to create something into project.json but It's not exists to project

Comment: The `project.json` file format is no-longer used by .NET Core, see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/11/notes-from-the-asp-net-community-standup-may-10-2016/

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET Team are trying to do something better than editing the project.json by hand.

> #### Question: project.json is going away?  Sadface
>
> What were the things we liked?  It was small, contained NuGet information, and could be edited by hand.  Damian does not want to lose any of those benefits, and that is why they are working in several steps to complete this migration.  Additionally, the team is building tooling at the command line so that you don’t have to work with the project file directly.  Consider a possible npm-like command like “dotnet install json.net –save” to add a NuGet package to your project.  There will be first class commands like this available.
>   The new MSBuild will not have a complete list of every file, so that should reduce the size of the build file.  It will still be XML, but the team is committed to making that experience better for all .NET projects.  This will be an enhanced MSBuild that has all of the best parts of project.json

Read more here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/11/notes-from-the-asp-net-community-standup-may-10-2016/

Comment: hummmm... so, how do i solve the exception i'm getting when running `dot net test`?